# Stripe implementation in my own form in an Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

I'm trying to get some value(total = total + itemJson.price * item.quantity) into my own form for stripe.

Every time I try to submit I get this error message:

```
"$ node server.js
C:\Users\Marcio\dsdrucker1\server.js:44 req.body.items.forEach(function(item) {
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
at C:\Users\Marcio\dsdrucker1\server.js:44:22
at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)".
```

Here below you can find my code I have written. What am I doing wrong?

```js
app.post('/checkout', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile('items.json', function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).end()
    } else {
      const itemsJson = JSON.parse(data)
      const itemsArray = itemsJson.roupa
      let total = 0
      req.body.items.forEach(function(item) {
        const itemJson = itemsArray.find(function(i) {
          return i.id == item.id
        })
        total = total + itemJson.price * item.quantity
      })
      
      stripe.charges.create({
        amount: total,
        source: req.body.stripeTokenId,
        currency: 'usd'
      }).then(function() {
        console.log('Charge Successful')
        res.json({ message: 'Successfully purchased items' })
      }).catch(function() {
        console.log('Charge Fail')
        res.status(500).end()
      })
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-offset-3">
        <h1>Checkout</h1>
        <h4>Your Total: ${{total}}</h4>
        <div id="charge-error" class="alert alert-danger {{#if noError}}hidden{{/if}}">
            {{errMsg}}
        </div>
        <form action="/checkout" method="post" id="checkout-form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" required name="name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="address">Address</label>
                        <input type="text" id="address" class="form-control" required name="address">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="card-name">Card Holder Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="card-name" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="card-number">Credit Card Number</label>
                        <input type="text" id="card-number" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="card-expiry-month">Expiration Month</label>
                                <input type="text" id="card-expiry-month" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="card-expiry-year">Expiration Year</label>
                                <input type="text" id="card-expiry-year" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="card-cvc">CVC</label>
                        <input type="text" id="card-cvc" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Buy now</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="checkout.js"></script>
```

This is the Js I used for my form

```js
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_BDlJ33LBsh5s6L69P5y3AAvp00ETkWe6tP');

var $form = $('#checkout-form');

$form.submit(function (event) {
    $('#charge-error').addClass('hidden');
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
    Stripe.card.createToken({
        number: $('#card-number').val(),
        cvc: $('#card-cvc').val(),
        exp_month: $('#card-expiry-month').val(),
        exp_year: $('#card-expiry-year').val(),
        name: $('#card-name').val()
    }, stripeResponseHandler);
    return false;
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    if (response.error) { // Problem!

        // Show the errors on the form
        $('#charge-error').text(response.error.message);
        $('#charge-error').removeClass('hidden');
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false); // Re-enable submission

    } else { // Token was created!

        // Get the token ID:
        var token = response.id;

        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server:
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));

        // Submit the form:
        $form.get(0).submit();

    }
}
```

Comment: It means that req.body.items doesn't exist. There is nothing in your HTML form that implies the existence of such a field.

Comment: As @i.brod mentions, you are getting the error because you don't have any `items` in the body. To proceed, you should try to attach a debugger and inspect the req.body or simply add a `console.log(req.body)` before the line containing `req.body.items.forEach...`.

Comment: first of all thank you, i added a console.log and the result is :"$ node server.js
{}
C:\Users\Marcio\dsdrucker1\server.js:41
      req.body.items.forEach(function(item) {
                     ^"                                                      but in the html from my shop i have a ejs.function  <% items.roupa.forEach(function(item){ %>, what iswrong?